# Decimal points - Probability value of 0 in Language R

Tags: r, decimal, probability, numerical

How to treat p value in R ?

I am expecting very low p values like:

```
1.00E-80
```

I need to -log10

```
-log10(1.00E-80)
```

-log10(0) is Inf, but Inf at sense of rounding too.

But is seems that after 1.00E-308, R yields 0.

```
1/10^308  
[1] 1e-308

 1/10^309 
[1] 0
```

Is the accuracy of p-value display with `lm` function the same as the cutoff point, 1e-308, or it is just designed such that we need a cutoff point and I need to consider a different cutoff point - such as 1e-100 (for example) to replace 0 with <1e-100.

Comment: It has always seemed statistically suspect to be worrying about the differences in p-values in those extreme ranges. The violations of assumptions underlying the calculations would seem to be serious. So you appear to be asking for a precise answer to a question whose premise is highly suspect.

Comment: This is done a lot in bioinformatics, and I think often in non-silly ways: the p-values are taken as indices of strength of signal, not as literal probabilities.  (Arguably an effect size metric like the t-statistic would be more transparent, but wouldn't lead to very different conclusions from the p-value approach.)

Comment: (The question involved `lm` which suggested to me that discrete models were not being used.) This is probably the wrong venue in which to hash out the many failures at getting preliminary reports of genomic associations to be reproduced, but that would appear to be explained by a failure to properly penalize the inferential methods.

Comment: I would say data snooping and underestimation of systematic errors are more likely culprits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a variety of possible answers -- which one is most useful depends on the context:

- R is indeed incapable under ordinary circumstances of storing floating-point values closer to zero than `.Machine$double.xmin`, which varies by platform but is typically (as you discovered) on the order of `1e-308`.  If you really need to work with numbers this small and can't find a way to work on the log scale directly, you need to search Stack Overflow or the R wiki for methods for dealing with arbitrary/extended precision values (but you probably should try to work on the log scale -- it will be much less of a hassle)
- in many circumstances R actually computes p values on the (natural) log scale internally, and can if requested return the log values rather than exponentiating them before giving the answer.  For example, `dnorm(-100,log=TRUE)` gives -5000.919. You can convert directly to the log10 scale (without exponentiating and then using `log10`) by dividing by `log(10)`: `dnorm(-100,log=TRUE)/log(10)`=-2171, which would be too small to represent in floating point.  For the `p***` (cumulative distribution function) functions, use `log.p=TRUE` rather than `log=TRUE`. (This particular point depends heavily on your particular context. Even if you are not using built-in R functions you may be able to find a way to extract results on the log scale.)
- in some cases R presents p-value results as being `<2.2e-16` even when a more precise value is known: `(t1 <- t.test(rnorm(10,100),rnorm(10,80)))`

prints

```
....
t = 56.2902, df = 17.904, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

but you can still extract the precise p-value from the result

```
> t1$p.value
[1] 1.856174e-18
```

(in many cases this behaviour is controlled by the `format.pval()` function)

An illustration of how all this would work with `lm`:

```
d <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5,each=10))
set.seed(101)
d$y <- rnorm(50,mean=d$x,sd=0.0001)
lm1 <- lm(y~x,data=d)
```

`summary(lm1)` prints the p-value of the slope as `<2.2e-16`, but if we use `coef(summary(lm1))` (which does not use the p-value formatting), we can see that the value is 9.690173e-203.

A more extreme case:

```
set.seed(101); d$y <- rnorm(50,mean=d$x,sd=1e-7)
lm2 <- lm(y~x,data=d)
coef(summary(lm2))
```

shows that the p-value has actually underflowed to zero.  However, we can still get an answer on the log scale:

```
tval <- coef(summary(lm2))["x","t value"]
2*pt(abs(tval),df=48,lower.tail=FALSE,log.p=TRUE)/log(10)
```

gives -692.62 (you can check this approach with the previous example where the p-value doesn't overflow and see that you get the same answer as printed in the summary).

Comment: @Ben Bolker, thanks for great answer....it seems than normal probablity has less cap than lm prob value 1-pnorm(8) =  6.661338e-16,1-pnorm(9)= 0, any suggestion on this ?

Comment: In that case you probably want `pnorm(8,lower.tail=FALSE,log.p=TRUE)` for maximum precision

Answer (score 3):

Small numbers are generally hard to deal with.

The limit in R for infinite is caused by the use of double precision floating point :

?double All R platforms are required to work with values conforming to the IEC 60559 (also known as IEEE 754) standard. This basically works with a precision of 53 bits, and represents to that precision a range of absolute values from about 2e-308 to 2e+308.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format

You may find the *Rmpfr* package helpful here as it allows you to create multiple precision numbers.

```
install.packages("Rmpfr")
require(Rmpfr)

log(mpfr(1/10^309, precBits=500))
```

Comment: good answer about the numerics, but I think the OP will be better served by finding a way to work directly on the log scale rather than messing around with higher precision ...